# Get /print fatal error message in PHP

Tags: php, error-handling

How can I retrieve the message-only from a fatal error message in php store it as a variable.

I'm running a script which I believe has some custom error reporting on it when it runs. When the function fails, I get this:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'functionName' with message 'the was an error' in 'filepath.php line 10'
```

I have error reporting turned on like this:

```
<?php
error_reporting( E_ALL );
ini_set( "display_errors", 1 );
?>
```

However, I'd like to store the error message as variable that I can use in a more user-friendly way.

So far I've tried this:

```
$var = error_get_last(['message']);
echo $var;
```

But it doesn't display anything.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you read the manual? http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.error-get-last.php

Comment: you could install xdebug for PHP and it will have a stack like interface to help debug the error.

Comment: also read: http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php